# Minimizing the criterion function $f(a) = \int_0^1 [g(x) - p(x)]^2\ dx$ by a polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, maxima-minima

> We can approximate a function $g$ in the interval $[0,1]$ by a
>   polynomial of degree $\le n$ by minimizing the criterion function:
>
> $$f(a) = \int_0^1 [g(x) - p(x)]^2\ dx$$
>
> where $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_n x^n$. Find the equations that
>   the optimal coefficients have to satisfy.

I normally would try to take the partials and equate to $0$:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_j} = \int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_j}(g(x)-p(x))^2\ dx = \int_0^12(g(x)-p(x))x^j\ dx$$

So I know that at least it should satisfy $\int_0^1(g(x)-p(x))x^j\ dx = 0$. I think that by optimal it means that it's either a maximum or a minimum, not a saddle, right? So the hessian should satisfy something to: either positive definite or negative definite. Am I right? Then

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a_i\partial a_j} = 2\int_0^1-x^jx^i\ dx = -2\int_0^1 x^{i+j}\ dx = \frac{-2x^{i+j+1}}{i+j+1}|_{x=1} = \frac{-2}{i+j+1}$$

Let $M$ be the matrix with these elements, then I'd have $x^tMx>0$ or $x^tMx<0$ depending on the case (minimum or maximum).

I know these $2$ conditions, when met, should let to $x$ be a minimum or maximum. Is this it? The exercise says 'find the equations that the optimal coefficients have to satisfy'. What are optimal coefficients exactly?

Comment: I think by optimal it means the minimum, not maximum and not a saddle point.

Comment: The equations $\int_0^1 (g)x) - p(x))x^j ~ dx = 0 $ can be written by explicitly computing $\int_0^1 p(x) x^j ~ dx$, which depends on coefficients only. However I believe this would be valid if you prove the positive-definitenness of matrix $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the goal is to approximate $g$ by the polynomial $p$, the optimal coefficients would be those that minimize the given integral (so that $g\approx p$). The determinant of the Hessian matrix must then be $>0$.

When the first derivatives are set to zero, the linearity of integration allows to write it as a system of $n$ equations with the coefficient of $a_k$ being $-\int_0^1 x^{k+j}\ dx$. This can be solved with Cramer's rule if desired.

Comment: What do I do with $\int_0^1 p(x)\ dx$? Wouldn't $a_k$ depend on this too?

Comment: If you are just trying to find the coefficients that make $p(x)$ the polynomial of best fit over the specified interval then I do not know why you would want to consider $\int_0^1 p(x)\ dx$. Are there some boundary conditions that it must also satisfy?

Comment: The integral of the function to approximate (times $x^j$) does appear as a constant in the system: $$\sum_k a_k\int_0^1 x^{k+i}\ dx=\int_0^1 x^i g(x)\ dx$$ The integral of the polynomial does not.